# Execute file with double click

Tags: python3

```
#! /home/mehmet/anaconda3/bin/python3

from os import pipe, sep
import os
import time
import math

os.system("figlet SAYI BULMACA")

rakam1 = [[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15],
          [17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31],
          [33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47],
          [51,53,55,57,59,61,63]]
rakam2 = [[2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15],
          [18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31],
          [34,35,38,39,42,43,46,47],
          [50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63]]
rakam3 = [[4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15],
          [20,21,22,23,28,29,30,31],
          [36,37,38,39,44,45,46,47],
          [52,53,54,55,60,61,62,63]]
rakam4 = [range(8,16),
          range(24,32),
          range(40,48),
          range(56,64)]
rakam5 = [range(16,24),
          range(24,32),
          range(48,56),
          range(56,64)]
rakam6 = [range(32,40),
          range(40,48),
          range(48,56),
          range(56,64)]          

time.sleep(2)

print("""

    Sayı bulmaca oyunumuza hoş geldiniz.

    Şimdi sizden aklınızda 1 ve 63 dahil olacak şekilde 
    1'den 63'e kadar bir sayı tutmanızı istiyorum.

    Sonrasında siz bir takım sayılar göstereceğim ve tuttuğunuz sayının
    gördüğünüz sayılar içerisinde olup olmadığını soracağım.

    Bu şekilde tuttuğunuz sayıyı bulmayaca çalışacağım.
    
    """)
    
tahmin_basla = input("Aklınızdan bir sayı tuttunuz mu?\nE/H\nBitirmek için H'ye basabilirsiniz\n")



skor = []

sayi = 0

while sayi < 1:

    if tahmin_basla == "e":
        print("İyi eğlenceler dilerim")
    else:
        print("Oyunu bitiriyorum")
        break
            
    

    for i in rakam1:
        print(*i)
    tahmin1 = input("Tutuğunuz sayı bu rakamlar içerisinde var mı?\nVAR(V) / YOK(Y)\n")
    if tahmin1 == "v":
        skor.append(int(1))

    time.sleep(1)    
        
    for i in rakam2:
        print(*i)
    tahmin2 = input("Tutuğunuz sayı bu rakamlar içerisinde var mı?\nVAR(V) / YOK(Y)\n")
    if tahmin2 == "v":
        skor.append(int(2))
        
    time.sleep(1)   

    for i in rakam3:
        print(*i)
    tahmin3 = input("Tutuğunuz sayı bu rakamlar içerisinde var mı?\nVAR(V) / YOK(Y)\n")
    if tahmin3 == "v":
        skor.append(int(4))
        
    time.sleep(1)   

    for i in rakam4:
        print(*i)
    tahmin4 = input("Tutuğunuz sayı bu rakamlar içerisinde var mı?\nVAR(V) / YOK(Y)\n")
    if tahmin4 == "v":
        skor.append(int(8))
        
    time.sleep(1)   

    for i in rakam5:
        print(*i)
    tahmin5 = input("Tutuğunuz sayı bu rakamlar içerisinde var mı?\nVAR(V) / YOK(Y)\n")
    if tahmin5 == "v":
        skor.append(int(16))
        
    time.sleep(1)   

    for i in rakam6:
        print(*i)
    tahmin6 = input("Tutuğunuz sayı bu rakamlar içerisinde var mı?\nVAR(V) / YOK(Y)\n")
    if tahmin6 == "v":
        skor.append(int(32))
            
    time.sleep(1)   

    bildin = sum(skor)

    print("Şimdi tahmin etmeye çalışıyorum...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f"Tuttuğunuz sayı : {bildin}\n"
            "Oynadığınız için teşekkürler\n")
    
    time.sleep(1)   

    sayi =+ 1

    if sayi == 1:
        sorucevap = input("Tekrar Oynamak ister misiniz?\nE/H\n")
        if sorucevap == "e":
            sayi = 0
        else:
            print("Görüşmek üzere....")
            break
```

Hello, I'm working with the Python language as an amateur, and a few months ago, I decided to use Ubuntu after Windows 10 and switched. Of course, I also know how to use Linux distributions at the beginner level.

I prepared the code you see above with Visual Studio Code and saved it with a .py extension.

My goal is to:

As in Windows, I want the code to run by double-clicking the file and close it after a person uses it. When running, it does not matter whether it is a window or a terminal screen.

First of all, I have to point out that I tried several ways for this process:

1. `pyinstaller -F filename.py` I created an exe into dist / file it didn't work.
2. I tried it with `chmod u + x filename`.
3. I activated the ask option when opening the properties. I don't want him to ask me what will happen after double-clicking
4. I created a file with a .desktop extension. I have pasted codes into it (I don't know if the codes are correct.)

As a result, I could not do anything.

Can someone please explain in detail what to do?

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED

my problem is solved

exec = gnome-terminal -e "python3 file path / filename.py" >>> all problem is this

my problem was solved.

[Desktop Entry]
Version = 1.0
Type = Application
Name = Run
Comment = Terminal Execution
Exec = gnome-terminal -e "python3 /home/here is username/Desktop/Myprograms/Shortcut.py"
Icon = emblem-dropbox-syncing
Path =
Terminal = false
StartupNotify = false

Comment: That's not the correct way to solve the problem. Maybe the issue is related to Python version. [Check this answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.desktop%20python?sort=MostVotes&edited=true)

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the first line of your script. There should be **no space** between shebang (`#!`) and the path to Python interpreter (`/home/mehmet/anaconda3/bin/python3` - also check if this path is correct and fix it if not). If you remove this and make the file executable, it should run after double click.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276845

Comment: So probably incorrect path to Python interpreter.

Comment: I don't think so. That's where Anaconda installs Python 3

Comment: Looks like GNOME actually doesn't properly recognize .py files as executables. I checked with a simple "hello world" script, that runs OK from command line. However, when double-clicked, GNOME doesn't recognize that it has x bit set and opens it in text editor. Also after clicking on "Open with a different program" there's no Python interpreter available to associate with .py extension (but this shouldn't be needed in first place, as the file has the x bit set). Looks like a bug in GNOME?

Comment: That's 2 year old thing. See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/nautilus-remove-ability-launch-binaries-apps

Comment: You should post it as an answer, as it pretty much explains the issue. BTW. I just a few months ago migrated from 10.04 (!) to 20.04 (using shortly Ubuntu MATE 18.04 in the meantime, never fully moved to it) and wasn't aware of this. That's pretty bad...